# Using multiple meta data in WP queries

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I use multiple metadata in a `WP_query` ?

I am able to use meta `key` and `value` within my query, but when I try to include more than one, I get no result (there are definitely posts which have this set)

This is the `$arg` array I'm trying.

```
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'promote_to_homepage',
                        'value' => '1',
                        'compare' => '=='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'make_feature',
                        'value' => '1',
                        'compare' => '=='
                    )
            )
        );
```

I would like the query to only pull in posts which have `promote_to_homepage` set as `true` (1) and also `make_feature` set as `true` (1).

The code above gets no results.

I've tried with values: `1`,`'1'`, `true` `'true'`, and the choice for the checkbox which is `Make Feature` and also `"Make feature"`

I have tried the following, as per the example in the docu posted in comments:

```
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'promote_to_homepage',
                        'value' => '"promote to homepage"',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'make_feature',
                        'value' => '"make feature"',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
            )
        );
```

Comment: Do you save the meta values as boolean string: 'true' or as '1' ?

Comment: @birgire they are Advanced Custom Field checkboxes: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/ I have tried `1`, `true`, `"My Choice"` and `My Choice` - none have worked

Comment: I should also say, when I only include one meta value and key pair, and use `1` it works.

Comment: How does it looks like in your database?

Comment: @birgire this is the value of the meta_value field in the DB: `a:1:{i:0;s:19:"Promote to homepage";}`

Comment: There you have the reason why your query doesn't work - This isn't equal to 1 - This is a serialized array - They don't work so well with SQL ;-) You might try LIKE or REGEXP comparisons or find a hook where you can add this value as your own single meta value.

Comment: @birgire can you provide a code example for the use of LIKE? I'm a bit confused still as to what I am doing wrong. This is an ACF custom field

Comment: You've an example on the ACF page link you gave previously, check it out.

Comment: @birgire I have tried as per the example in the docu, have posted code in OP. Still getting no results.

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end.

The value should be the first part of the choice parameter. In my case this was `make feature`

The comparison should be `LIKE`

Here is my example:

```
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'promote_to_homepage',
                        'value' => 'promote to homepage',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'make_feature',
                        'value' => 'make feature',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
            )
        );
```